# C# - Using NumberFormatInfo with Convert.ToDouble to return double

Tags: c#, globalization

In my application I have internationalization and so we have a bunch of methods to deal with formatting.
One of them should receive a double and format it to two decimal places and return a **double**. For doing so, we are using `NumberFormatInfo` according to the culture selected.

The problem is I cant get `Convert.ToDouble` to work with `NumberFormatInfo` the way I would like to. Basically what I want to know is why this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myDouble = 9.983743;

        var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo() {
            NumberDecimalDigits = 2
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Original value: " + myDouble);
        Console.WriteLine("Converted value: " + Convert.ToDouble(myDouble, nfi));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Original value: 9.983743
Converted value: 9.983743 // Should be 9.98
```

And how can I get the result I want using `NumberFormatInfo` only, if possible.

Thanks,

Comment: That's because converting a `double` to a `double` isn't going to change the `double`.  You want to format the `string` representation of the `double`.  That or actually round or truncate the `double` in question.

Comment: Even if `myDouble` was a `string`, it would still not round the number. So basically, what is the purpose of the `NumberFormatInfo` parameter in the `Convert.ToDouble` method?

Comment: Basically `NumberFormatInfo` can be used both for parsing a `string` to a number and for formatting a number to a `string`.  So some of it's settings are only for one of those two uses.

Comment: Among the parameters for `NumberFormatInfo` I think this is one of the few that would make sense applying to a `double`. The other ones are really only about presenting the number (currency symbol, plus signal, etc). Thats a boomer :/ 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you see my answer? I show you how to round your number to 2 digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits.aspx):

> The NumberDecimalDigits property is used with the "F" and "N" standard format strings without a precision specifier in numeric formatting operations.

The default is the generic formatting (`G`). So this will give you the desired result:

```
Console.WriteLine(myDouble.ToString("N", nfi));
```

However, 2 is the default value anyway. And it is better to specify it explicitly:

```
Console.WriteLine(myDouble.ToString("N2", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
```

**Update:**

> Yeah but I do need to return a double from my method.

Now I see. In your place I would return the original `double` in that case, too. If the consumer of your API wants to display/store it as a string with two digits, then it is his responsibility to format it.

If you really want to omit the last digits of the precision and return a modified value, then use `Math.Round` instead (but I would not recommend that).

Comment: Yeah but I do need to return a `double` from my method. This value is returned to the client and should be a `double`. I would like to rely only on a single method using the `NumberFormatInfo` (since this is set when user selects the language of the application) and not be casting it to `string` and then back to `double`... Do you think thats possible?

Comment: @JoãoMenighin You're getting formatting and manipulation mixed up.  You should basically keep a value as is within your system and only worry about formatting when displaying.  If you actually need to round a value then you'd use the appropriate math functions.

Comment: I do agree with you @taffer, the one thing I can't get my head around is what the `NumberFormatInfo` parameter is used for in the `Convert.ToDouble` if not for this kind of "formatting". Do you know?

Comment: The whole `Convert` class is good for converting the `IConvertible` types into each other. All primitive types implement `IConvertible`, including `string`. The `Convert` methods with `IFormatProvider` parameter are used only when you are converting to or from `string` or `object` (`NumberFormatInfo` is an implementation of `IFormatProvider`). Specifically, `Convert.ToDouble(string,IFormatProvider)` is actually a `double.Parse()` call. When parsing a string, the culture-dependent decimal separator, thousands separator, negative sign symbol are taken from `NumberFormatInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You state you want to **return a `double`** with only 2 digits after the decimal place. Therefore, you are not *formatting* you are *[rounding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx)*:

```
Math.Round(myDouble, 2)
```

> 9.98

Answer (score 0):

Converting a double to a double does not change anything, a double is always double precision, you cannot change the number of decimal digits.

A double has no format, format comes into play when you display a double by using the ToString() method as explained by taffer.

You can round it down to set all digits after the first 2 to zero, but you cannot remove digits.